# Hooking the kernel without a driver?

Tags: windows, dll, hook, pinvoke

Is it possible to hook a kernel level windows function without writing a device driver, or is that part of the definition of API hooking?

Comment: pinvoke? You want to hook the kernel from .net?!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I want to hook some kernel activity but preferably without writing a driver?

Comment: Patching kernel mode from user mode would be a serious security vulnerability if possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible. In fact, due to PatchGuard, it is quite difficult to hook kernel functions even *with* a kernel driver.

Now, if you just want to find out when things happen and get *information*, ETW will provide you a **ton** of information that you would traditionally would think requires kernel hooks (though you cannot intercept and stop these calls, only see when they happen). Check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/08/27/etw-introduction-and-overview.aspx) for more info.

Comment: what does http://www.oblita.com/interception.html do?